# Facing '401:Unauthorized' issue when updating JIRA issue status through C#

Tags: c#, jira, rest

I am trying to update status of an issue in JIRA using C# code. I found various curl codes for the same, but since I am unfamiliar to curl, I converted the code to C#.

Now, the first error I am facing is "Status code: 401", "Unauthorized". I am using email and API token to authorize. Searched and read through all the blogs/questions, found very similar issues but unable to figure out the issue with my code.

Also I am new to C# and Jira environment, it would be great if you could help me out with finding the error. Or if I am missing something in the code?

See code below:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), "https://<myhostname>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/<project>-<issueno>"))
{
var username = "<my-email>";
var password = "<API Token>";
var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

request.Content = new StringContent("{\"transition\":{\"id\":\"11\"}}");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
Console.WriteLine(response);
}
}
```

**Edit:**
Replacing "Basic" with "Bearer" resolved 401 error but getting '400 Bad Request' error now. Figured out it's because of the JSON that we pass to update the issue, so did a bit of changes in there. Now I'm simply trying to update summary of the issue. Can anybody please help me find the cause and resolve the issue?

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), "https://<host-url>/rest/api/2/issue/<issue-key>"))
                {
                    var username = "<username>";
                    var password = "<API Key>";
                    string data = @"{'update' : {'summary' : [{'set' : 'Big block Chevy'}]}}";
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {base64authorization}");

                    request.Content = new StringContent($"{data}");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Bhawna

Comment: Not directly a solution but if I run into issues like this I like to use Postman to see if I can get a correct HTTP request configured. Once I have that working I use the same setup in my code. It often makes it a bit easier to see what you're doing and quickly iterate.

Comment: It may use a bearer token. If so, then this will not work: TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");. Remove Basic and replace it with bearer

Comment: Hi @GHDevOps thank you for the response. This actually solved my problem but now I am facing a new error- '400 Bad Request'. I checked the internet and it is mainly if the JSON that we are passing to make changes in the issue, is incorrect. But I copied the exact content as given on JIRS's official site. Could you please help me out with this one? I am unable to figure out the issue. Updating the code in above question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue of "401 Unauthorized" by changing my code to **Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes** but that alone didn't help me. Replacing "Basic" with "Bearer" in the following line did help me resolve 401 error.

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` to get the byte representation of your string but you should use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` since that's what `ToBase64String` is expecting. Changing that part of your code should fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Kort. I did change my code to Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes but that alone didn't help me. Replacing "Basic" with "Bearer" did help me resolve 401 error. But now I have a new error- '400 Bad Request'- I researched to find it arises due to error in JSON that we are passing to update the issue. But I'm unable to figure out the error, could you please help me with this? Or is there any other reason for this error. Thanks. (Updated the question)

Comment: @BhawnaPareta I would suggest writing a new question with the new problem as the title as that would help people with that particular knowledge to spot it. Don't change the title of this question, it will help other people getting 401 errors in the future.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu sure i'll do that. Thank you for the suggestion.